# unbuffered read from stdin in python

Tags: python, stdin, unbuffered

I'm writing  a python script that can read input through a pipe from another command like so

```
batch_job | myparser
```

My script `myparser` processes the output of `batch_job` and write to its own stdout. My problem is that I want to see the output immediately (the output of batch_job is processed line-by-line) but there appears to be this notorious stdin buffering (allegedly 4KB, I haven't verified) which delays everything.

The problem has been discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565493/read-from-stdin-in-python-process) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033781/how-to-avoid-python-fileinput-buffering) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

I tried the following:

- open stdin using `os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'r', 0)`
- using `-u` in my hashbang: `#!/usr/bin/python -u`
- setting `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` right before calling the script
- flushing my *output* after each line that was read (just in case the problem was coming from output buffering rather than input buffering)

My python version is 2.4.3 - I have no possibility of upgrading or installing any additional programs or packages. How can I get rid of these delays?

Comment: Are you sure the buffering is happening in Python, on stdin, and not on the batch job's stdout?  Sometimes applications check the device type of stdout, and base their buffering on what it is, so just because it might appear to be line buffering when writing to a terminal doesn't mean it will do the same when piped to another process.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I will try to verify. What I can say is that the application is itself shell script.

Comment: It also creates a log file with identical content to what's normally written to the terminal. I observe that this log file is updated faster i.e. it will already contain the lines that my script is still waiting for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting smaller buffer size for sys.stdin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin)

Comment: @DenilsonSá : no I had looked at that question. The answer which was marked as the solution there is using the -u option, which as I explained, didn't work in my case.

Comment: I do think it may be a dup of your second "here"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033781/how-to-avoid-python-fileinput-buffering , which is incorrectly marked as a dup of yet another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670323/setting-smaller-buffer-size-for-sys-stdin .  A good workaround is to use readline (however first use strace to confirm that the bad behavior is within python, rather than output buffering in your batch_job... it could be either or both!).  See that other Q for more info.

Comment: Why don't you just launch the `batch_job` from within your `myparser` as a subprocess and then you get to fully control STDOUT/STDIN? The way you have it set up doesn't depend only on Python but also on shell buffering itself.

Comment: As already pointed out by others, it's more likely to be an output buffering of `batch_job`. Have you tried to run it with `stdbuf -o0 -e0` as suggested in the question you've linked (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378)?

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue with legacy code. It appears to be a problem with the implementation of Python 2's `file` object's `__next__` method; it uses a Python level buffer (which `-u`/`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` doesn't affect, because those only unbuffer the `stdio` `FILE*`s themselves, but `file.__next__`'s buffering isn't related; similarly, `stdbuf`/`unbuffer` can't change any of the buffering at all, because Python replaces the default buffer made by the C runtime; the last thing [`file.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L2418) does for a newly opened file is call `PyFile_SetBufSize` which uses `setvbuf`/`setbuf` [the APIs] to replace the default `stdio` buffer).

The problem is seen when you have a loop of the form:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

where the first call to `__next__` (called implicitly by the `for` loop to get each `line`) ends up blocking to fill the block before producing a single line.

There are three possible fixes:

1. (Only on Python 2.6+) Rewrap `sys.stdin` with the `io` module (backported from Python 3 as a built-in) to bypass `file` entirely in favor of the (frankly superior) Python 3 design (which uses a single system call at a time to populate the buffer without blocking for the full requested read to occur; if it asks for 4096 bytes and gets 3, it'll see if a line is available and produce it if so) so:

   ```
   import io
   import sys

   # Add buffering=0 argument if you won't always consume stdin completely, so you 
   # can't lose data in the wrapper's buffer. It'll be slower with buffering=0 though.
   with io.open(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', closefd=False) as stdin:
       for line in stdin:
           # Do stuff with the line
   ```

   This will typically be faster than option 2, but it's more verbose, and requires Python 2.6+. It also allows for the rewrap to be Unicode friendly, by changing the mode to `'r'` and optionally passing the known `encoding` of the input (if it's not the locale default) to seamlessly get `unicode` lines instead of (ASCII only) `str`.
2. (Any version of Python) Work around problems with `file.__next__` by using `file.readline` instead; despite nearly identical intended behavior, `readline` doesn't do its own (over)buffering, it delegates to C `stdio`'s `fgets` (default build settings) or a manual loop calling `getc`/`getc_unlocked` into a buffer that stops exactly when it hits end of line. By combining it with two-arg `iter` you can get nearly identical code without excess verbosity (it'll probably be slower than the prior solution, depending on whether `fgets` is used under the hood, and how the C runtime implements it):

   ```
   # '' is the sentinel that ends the loop; readline returns '' at EOF
   for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
       # Do stuff with line
   ```
3. Move to Python 3, which doesn't have this problem. :-)

Comment: Note: Obviously, if `batch_job` has buffered output, you need to unbuffer it or make sure it does manual flushes so there is anything for the Python program to see. But I've definitely seen cases where the prior process was *definitely* unbuffered, and Python 2's `for line in sys.stdin:` is responsible for the buffering (where non-Python 2 programs subbed in to the pipeline, using raw I/O or plain C `stdio`, don't have the problem).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, bash, what you are looking for seems to be the stdbuf command.

If you want no buffering (i.e. an unbuffered stream), try this,

```
# batch_job | stdbuf -o0 myparser
```

If you want line buffering, try this,

```
# batch_job | stdbuf -oL myparser
```

Comment: This won't help. The problem isn't output buffering by Python (if it was, the `-u` flag or doing `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` before calling the script would fix it; `stdbuf` [the command line tool] doesn't work on programs that modify the default `stdio` buffering with `setvbuf`/`setbuf` [the APIs] in any event, and Python can and does do this), it Python buffering the *input*. And the buffering on the input is done in a Python user mode buffer that `stdbuf` (the command line tool) can't affect.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Well, it actually works.   I tested this by feeding data between two python programs,   with and without  stdbu -o0, and the difference is very clear.   So, that is the fact.  And it is unfair of you to down vote based on your speculations, and without trying it.

Comment: It may work in some scenarios, but not on Python 2.x in the scenarios where `-u`/`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` doesn't help already. You're likely being fooled by a test case that isn't the same as the OP's (e.g. in your case, your input pipe was also Python; the OP's only had it for the output from the pipe). Simple `bash` one-liner example that does not work: `(for ((i = 0; i < 10; ++i)); do echo $i && sleep 1; done) | stdbuf -o0 python2 -c 'for line in __import__("sys").stdin: print line,'`; you get no output for 10 seconds. Cause is the buffering in `file.__next__`, which `stdbuf` doesn't affect.

Comment: Replace `__import__("sys").stdin` with `iter(__import__("sys").stdin.readline, "")` and you'll get an output every second. If you can show me a single example where `stdbuf` on the right side of the pipe solves problems not solved by the various things the OP tried, I'll happily convert my downvote to an upvote. But I don't think such scenarios exist (as [`stdbuf`'s man page notes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) "If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does for e.g.) then that will override corresponding settings changed by 'stdbuf'."; Python 2 does that).

Comment: @ShadowRanger  The input was from a C-program, and yes it was python2.  It was a deployed imaging system, MIMO array from C, to image display and AI in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbuffer the output:

```
unbuffer batch_job | myparser
```