# Why is my program not sending keyboard data over socket?

Tags: python, sockets, buffering

I have a simple program designed to send raw text data over a TCP socket. I'm thinking this is a buffering problem; but I am not sure. No data appears to be sent.

```
from threading import Thread as thread
from sys import argv
from socket import socket
from tty import setraw
from sys import stdin
from sys import stdout
def rx(so):
    while True:
        stdout.write(so.recv(1).replace("\n", "\n\r"))
setraw(stdin.fileno())
so = socket()
so.connect((argv[1], int(argv[2])))
thread(target=rx, args=(so, )).start()
while True: so.send(stdin.read(1))
```

EDIT to clarify:
Keyboard data is not being sent.

Comment: This won't send anything unless you send it something. `\n\r` is wrong, it should be `\r\n`.

Comment: Q: Did you hit "return" anywhere in your keystokes?  Stdin *WILL* buffer data until you hit "return"...

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, but it's supposed to be unbuffered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Minor quibble:**

   As  user207421 said, "\n\r" is wrong.  The correct DOS CR/LF sequence is `'\r\n'`.
   Who knows - maybe you don't need that "replace()" at all.
2. **First Step: verify you can send/receive *anything***:

   Q: Do you see data returned from your socket when you type a few characters, then hit "return"?

   Please confirm "Yes" or "No".
3. **Python socket: Try disabling Nagle**:

   Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826762/):

   ```
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
   ```
4. **Raw keyboard input:**

   If you've verified steps 2 and 3 (you're able to send and receive data, and socket buffering isn't an issue), then you've isolated the problem to "stdin buffering".

   Look here for additional suggestions:  [unbuffered read from stdin in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305131/unbuffered-read-from-stdin-in-python)
5. **Additional suggestion:**

   For troubleshooting, can also try sending socket data from a *different* program: "telnet", "curl", a second Python script, etc. etc.

Please post back and let us know what you find!